# Need to hide RSS feeds converted to JS if certain keywords are met in JS result

Tags: php, javascript, filter, rss, hide

I am very new to PhP and JS.
I have a website that tracks multiple RSS feeds in one. I have done this with the use of third party websites that let me convert the RSS into a javascript function with CSS styling.

I've noticed sometimes an RSS feed will go offline on the host end for whatever reason, but I want to be able to use PhP or some other method to recognize certain keywords in the JS result and simply not display that feed.
I have no PhP in the page yet, just HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Below is one of the JS feeds I am using.

`src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?
src=http%3A%2F%2Fajaxplorer.info%2Ffeed&chan=title&num=10&date=y&utf=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<noscript><a href="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fajaxplorer.info%2Ffeed&chan=title&num=10&date=y&utf=y&html=y">View RSS feed</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If u are using JQuery, i u can use this one code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Property Agents</title>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- including JQuery from google CDN -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="rss">
            <!-- here is your script, which will paste here news-->
            <script src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fajaxplorer.info%2Ffeed&chan=title&num=10&date=y&utf=y&html=y"></script>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var text,pos;
            $('.rss-item').each(function(){
                // getting html of each element
                text = $(this).html();
                // search text in item
                pos  = text.indexOf('AjaXplorer 4.2');
                // found? then hide it
                if (pos != -1)  $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code finds all  news with 'AjaXplorer 4.2' text and hides it.
Full working example (just for be sure it's working) u can see at 

http://pastehtml.com/view/car52rb92.html

**Declaimer**:
It's not good one solution. Better generate page with PHP and on server-side filter those news. It is easy task, dude. May be 10-20 lines of code. 
Idea is simple for php-solution:
1. get data from url with `file_get_contents`
2. then pass through lines and find what u need (parse with SimpleXML better)
3. output modified data in HTML page with one code line like `<?php echo %text ?>`